# What alternative do I have to the Private Taxonomy Terms module?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

I am developing a Drupal site in which every authenticated user must have the privilege of creating new taxonomy terms, and only those taxonomy terms created by the user are shown on the content type. It should work exactly like the [Private Taxonomy Terms](http://drupal.org/project/private_taxonomy) module.
The issue with that module is that it doesn't work with the Services module, and I need it.

Is there a module available for this purpose, or should I create a custom service for this purpose?

Comment: Please elaborate on "Doesn't work with services". Errors? Bugs? Crashes? Incompatabilities?

Comment: i dont do much coding in drupal all i can say is that the method taxonomy_get_tree($vid, $parent, -1, $max_depth) returns null in that case which is called in services module when action is getTree it has a callback function called taxonomy_service_get_tree which returns null

Comment: You mean you get an error when using services+taxonomy_private? Or that it does not give the desired result?

Comment: it gives an error 406 and asks for tid as a parameter always